# How to get system (BlueJ) to allocate unique number sequentially

Tags: java, tostring, bluej

/**File class  */

```
public class File {
   // The File name.       
   private String name;
   // The date file created.     
   private String date ;
   // The type of file - audio, image, video, doc.     
   private String type;
   // The size of the file - 2MB, 2KB etc.     
   private String size; 


/**
 * Create a file 
 */

public File(String Filename)
{
name = Filename;
date = ("MM/dd/yyyy");
type = ();
size = ();
}


/**
 * Return the name of a File.
 */

public String getName()
{
return name;
}


/**
 * Update system number when called to the output terminal 
 */

public void Systemnumber ()
   name.increment();
   if(name.Filename() == 0) { // it jus rolled over !
      i.increment();
   }
   updateDisplay();
}


/**
 * Print File description to the output terminal 
 */

public void updateDisplay ()
public String s = String.format ("%02d", i); // gives you "001" 
for (int i = 001; i < 1000; i++) {String sequence = String.format("%02d", i); }
{      
return  (i + "", '$this.Name + " " + $this.date + " " + $this.type + " " +$this.size; }  


/**
 * This method is called everytime Increment the return value one, rolling over to zeor if the limit is reached 
 */

public void updateDisplay ()
{ displayString = name.
(
value = (value +1) % limit;
)
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, it makes it much easier to read!

Comment: Please read this FAQ on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and clarify what problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're using BlueJ, I'll assume it's homework, so I won't answer the question as such, just give some pointers.

You need to store a counter in the File object, *but*, that counter needs to be shared between instances of the object. This counter can be used at construction time to get the number for each individual instance of File, which can then be stored for the instance in question.

---

What you are missing in your new update is the sequence number. You should store this in a static variable (so that it is shared between all instances of File) and then assign its current value to a member variable in the constructor, before incrementing the static variable for the next instantiation.

Comment: Thanks Rich, its sure is homework, and your pointers are noted but I do not understand, can you please advise further on what i should read, thanks

Comment: @Ali Hi, I can't answer in detail now, but will be able to do so in about 7 hours' time. If that's too late then let me know...

Comment: hi Rich i pasted a revised code below using Luc's code, please advise me on that. I can surely wait for you to advise. thanks

Comment: public class File { // The File name. private String Name; // The date file created. private timestamp date; // The type of file - audio, image, video, doc. private String type; // The size of the file - 2MB, 2KB etc. private String size; /** * Create a file / public File(string Filename) {name = Filename; date = ("MM/dd/yyyy"); type = 0; size = 0; } /* * Return the name of a File.*/ public string getName() {return name;} public String toString() {return $this.Name + " " + $this.date + " " + $this.type + " " +$this.size; } } }

Comment: I've added your code to your original question (you can edit your question as many times as you like), but the thing that is missing is the sequence number.

Comment: I have added a bit more detail to my answer, but am doing my best not to answer the question for you! :)

Comment: hi Rich, how do i edit my code ?  and add new like you did earlier for me, please advise, thanks

Comment: You should have a link with the text "Edit" just under the blue blobs saying bluej, java, tostring.

Comment: Thanks Rich, have updated the code further please advise, thanks

Comment: have managed to get it now - thanks Rich

Comment: @Ali I'm pleased you've managed to work it out. Because the answer to your question will be of value to other people, I suggest you edit your original question to make it more clear (at the moment it is just a block of code), and you add your own answer to the question, with how you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a private static integer, which you can call it whatever you want. I will call it `numberOfFileInstances`. In your constructor you will need to increment numberOfFileInstances by one.

Here is my example:

```
public class File {

    private static int numberOfFileInstances = 0;

    public File() {
        File.numberOfFileInstances++;
    }

}
```

Since your using BlueJ you'll be easily able to see that each time you create a new file object the numberOfFileInstance will be incremented by one. In BlueJ initialize 2 (or any number you would like grater than 1) File objects and double click on the object to bring up the inspector. Click on the "Show static fields" button and you should see private int numberOfFileInstance and the count of however many object you initialized.

Comment: To clarify the reason for numberOfFileInstances being private is so that no other object can  modify the count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but it sounds simple:

```
public String toString()  { 
    return this.Name + " " + this.date + " " + this.type + " " +this.size;
}
```

Comment: He needs an idea on how to *do* the sequence number (`001` in his example) if he wants to print more then one file.

Comment: Thanks Luc. please see my revised code below and advise, thanks

Comment: public class File {
// The File name.       
private String Name;
// The date file created.     
private timestamp date;
// The type of file - audio, image, video, doc.     
private String type;
// The size of the file - 2MB, 2KB etc.     
private String size; 

/** * Create a file */
public File(string Filename)
{name = Filename;
date = ("MM/dd/yyyy");
type = 0;
size = 0;
}
/** * Return the name of a File.*/
public string getName()
{return name;}
public String toString()  
{return $this.Name + " " + $this.date + " " + $this.type + " " +$this.size; }  } 
}

Comment: You should edit your question. The code is hard to read.

Comment: @Luc I have edited the question for Ali

Comment: @Ali As Rich wrote is his answer, what is missing is a sequential number. All you have to to is implement the solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a sequence counter, you might want to consider using a static integer which you increment for every file added.